# I'd like two different styles for the List component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have two list instances of the list component. I'd like them to have two different visual styles (skins), how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Add some code. Show us what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want only one understandable question :)

Comment: Are you saying that you have two list UI component instances, and you'd like to have them use separate skins so they look different?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to change an instance of a list component so it's skin/style (design) is different from another instance.

You can do this at runtime by using the list's `setStyle()` function.

Here is a list of styles you can change:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/List.html#styleSummary

More or customizing UI components.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f50.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f41.html